# How I can fix the errors of "import as gradle project", "open files from systems" in STS4?

Tags: java, spring, gradle, spring-tool-suite

I downloaded a repo folder from GitHub and tried to run it on STS4. I tried to import it as a gradle project as I did before, but when I clicked "finish", the window just refreshed itself and nothing happened. I tried again by clicking "next", when I got to the end, the window also did nothing but refreshing.

[image]

I tried again by simply "open file from directory", but it's been giving me an error.

[image]

Both methods worked for me in the past. I don't know why they stopped working today. I appreciate your help.

Comment: maybe there is something related to this error in the Error Log view? That might reveal more details about the underlying issue.

Comment: @MartinLippert It says "missing gradle project configuration file: .settings". From the answers to this question <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42393545/how-to-fix-missing-gradle-project-configuration-file-issue-in-buildship>, we should use "Existing Gradle Project", which is exactly what I did, but there was no response after I click "finish", the page just refreshed and nothing else happened.

Comment: do you have a `.settings` folder being a part of that project?